# prepositional phrase behind adjectives

Tags: adjectives, prepositional-phrases

> They may become active in consumer movements for political reasons.

There are two PPs in this sentence, but I am not sure what they modify,
do both PP go with the verb **become** or the adjective **active**,
and what is the term for this kind of PP, complement or adverb?

> The students are apathetic about politics in Japan.

There are also two PPs in this sentence, and the same question confuses me,
my guess is that the PP **about politics** goes with ***apathetic***,
while **in Japan** goes with the noun **politics**?

So both sentences have similar syntax,
but the first one have two PPs that modify the same thing, **verb(become)** or **adjective(active)**   ,
while the second one have two PPs that modify different things ,one with **adj(apathetic)** and one with **noun (Japan)**, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mostly right.

In sentence 1, *in consumer movements* is a complement of the adjective *active*, *for political reasons* modifies the predicate *become active in consumer movements*.

In sentence 2, *about politics* is a complement of the adjective *apathetic*. *in Japan* is a little ambiguous: it **probably** modifies the entire predication *Students are apathetic about politics* (which in effect would be understood as *Students in Japan are apathetic*), but it may be that it only modifies *politics* — that is, "Students are apathetic about Japanese politics (but may be excited about, say, Chinese politics)". Context will usually resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you! ‘for political reasons’modifies the predicate “become active **for** in consumer movements” , why is there a “for” and what does it stand for?

Comment: @Kathy Because I'm an idiot! I don't know how it got into my fingers on the keyboard.